# SQL Server Search Filters Slow With Big Table Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join, query-performance

I have a catalog of products available to the user (close to 1000 products).  These products are in categories and subcategories, have colors, prices, etc.  I want the user to be able to filter the results of this catalog based on some of this criteria.  Some of this filter criteria is keywords (i.e. find me a blue pen).  However, I'm running in to performance issues when joining a large table to search over in this query, specifically my colors table.  Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @keyword nvarchar(100)
SET @keyword = 'bag'

SELECT DISTINCT         
    SP.pk_storeProductID,
    dbo.getMaxPrice(SP.pk_storeProductID) AS maxPrice
FROM
    tblProduct P
INNER JOIN              
    tblStoreProduct SP ON P.pk_productID = SP.fk_productID
INNER JOIN              
    tblProductDescription PD ON P.pk_productID = PD.fk_productID
INNER JOIN              
    tblProductSubCategory PSC ON SP.pk_storeProductID = PSC.fk_productID
INNER JOIN              
    tblSubCategory SC ON PSC.fk_subCategoryID = SC.pk_subCategoryID
INNER JOIN              
    tblCategory C ON SC.fk_categoryID = C.pk_categoryID
LEFT OUTER JOIN         
    tblProductImprint PI ON P.pk_productID = PI.fk_productID
LEFT OUTER JOIN         
    tblProductColor PC ON P.pk_productID = PC.fk_productID
LEFT OUTER JOIN         
    tblColor COL ON PC.fk_colorID = COL.pk_colorID
WHERE                   
    P.blnActive = 1
    AND SP.blnStoreActive = 1
    AND SC.blnActive = 1
    AND C.blnActive = 1
    AND C.blnLocked = 0
    AND SP.fk_storeID = 74
    AND 1 = CASE WHEN CONTAINS(P.productNumber, @keyword) THEN 1 
                 WHEN CONTAINS(P.productName, @keyword) THEN 1 
                 WHEN CONTAINS(PD.productDesc, @keyword) THEN 1 
                 WHEN CONTAINS(PD.keywords, @keyword) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
             END
```

The query seems to get significantly bogged down when I join tblColor. The way my system handles product colors is via three tables: a product table, a product color table (which is just two foreign keys for product ID and color ID), and a table for just colors (has a primary key for color and the name of the color).  This table has 13,144 rows in it.  I need to join this table in order to search the color names for a keyword that is like it based on the user input (this is not shown in the query above).  Also, a product may not have colors associated with it, but I don't want to leave it out of the results, so I'm doing a left outer join on the color tables.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?  As it is now, a simple search can take up to 4 minutes to return results, and the culprit always seems to be that color table.  I have proper indexes on all of these tables, and full text index on the product, product description, and color tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: In the left joins, flip the Left and Right terms of the equality.  i.e. instead of PI.fk_productID = p.pk_productID use P.pk_productID = PI.fk_productID.

Currently, you're taking all of the records from the left table (left side of equal sign) and joining to all matching values on right side.  Your driving table (the tables with the PK values) should be on the left.

Comment: Also, the multiple "OR" statements could be enhanced by using a case statement:  AND 1 = CASE WHEN CONTAINS(P.ProductNumber,@Keyword) THEN 1 WHEN CONTAINS (P.ProductName,@KeyWord) THEN 1...   ELSE 0 END

Comment: I updated my left joins as you said, but the response time was actually slower.  Also, when I added the case statement, I get an error.  I've never used a case in a SQL statement, so I'm not entirely sure if I'm constructing that correctly.

Comment: If you're getting an error, then I can tell you that you are not constructing it correctly.  What is the case statement code as you've typed it, and what is the error?

Comment: You can see how I constructed it in my updated query in my original post.  The error I get is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword ELSE."  I suspect that the first CASE clause should have an expression between it and the first WHEN clause, correct?

Comment: Ah nevermind...I fixed it.  It was the last THEN clause.  Updated my original query.

Comment: Anyways...These updates to the query didn't increase performance by much.  It shaved off about 10 seconds, but the query still takes a good minute to return results.  Not good for a web application.  But I do appreciate you pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Another tip to help figure out where you can increase performance is by analyzing the I/O of the query.  In SSMS, go to Query in the menu, then choose Query Options.  Under "Execution" Click Advanced, and check the box for "Set Statistics IO".